# Text not visible in input type field in one particular field

Tags: html, css

Following is my code where i have used input type=text and that particular field's text is not visible.Please check the code and let me know if there is any error.

```
  .description{
width: 75%;
height: 38px;
padding-left: 1000px;
}

     <tr>
  <td>Description</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="Description" class="description"></td>
</div>
```

Comment: why `padding-left: 1000px;`? remove it and then check

Comment: `padding-left: 1000px;` ???

Comment: And please modify tag, as it more CSS, not PHP at all... EDIT: thanks for right tags added

Comment: padding-left: 1000px; :(

Comment: padding-left: I have used it to place that particular input box .I removed that line and checked,not working.

Comment: padding != margin ! padding applies to the **inside**, margin, to the *outside* (moving the element xx pixels from the document)

Comment: @JasmineLalani : added commented example, please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> there is a difference between **padding** and **margin**

Padding applies to the inside of the element (adds a kind of "inside border", like a frame, that pushes the content away from the border)
For example: applied to an input, a 10px padding will move the text from the border and position it 10px inside

Margin applies to the general position of the element.

> refer to [BOX models](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp)

Keep in mind that it applies from -> top / right / bottom / left

Padding 10px 25px 0 50px will do 10 on top, 25 on right, 0 at bottom, 50 on the left.

In your case, apply some **padding** to the table if you want to have more space between the title "Description" and the input named "Description":

Here's a example, play with it and adapt to your need :)

```
<style> 

.description {
width: 75%;
height: 38px;
padding: 10px;
}

.margin {
margin: 50px auto; // applies to TOP/BOTTOM (left/right is auto)
}

.padding {
padding: 25px; // applies to Top/Right/Bottom/Left
}

</style>


<div class="margin">
<table>
<tr>
<td class="padding">Description</td>
<td class="padding"><input type="text" name="Description" class="description"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

as it has been told in the comments. remove the `padding-left: 1000px;` from your CSS and you should see the text again. The padding pushes the text a 1000px to the right side of the screen. wich is out of the input field so not visible.

Check the following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qAhQf/592/) for a working example

Comment: `The padding pushes the text a 1000px to the left` ? or to the right maybe ? ^^

Comment: The space between textbox and field is too much,how can I reduce the space ?

Comment: @OldPadawan You're right. it is that it pushes the text a 1000px to the right side of the screen. i've corrected my answer. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: do you mean between the label and the input field? or between the 2 `<td>` elements @JasmineLalani

Comment: Yes, between label and the input field.I am really sorry for not being so specific.

Comment: check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qAhQf/592/) example. That should give the answer to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

First of all make sure you were posting the right code, bcoz u have opened `<tr>` but closed as `</div>` and there will not be any text in default and you was mentioning that the input which you are going to enter should be as text type.. If you need to have a Text by default you can add placeholder ="Some description", and to start the text from left side you should remove padding-left:1000px; and i have edited your code as follows,

The html as

```
  <tr>
    <td>Description</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Description" class="description"></td>
  </tr>
```

and css was,

```
.description{
width: 75%;
height: 38px;
}
```